# How can I add this transaction to when after email confirmation is completed with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Assuming that an existing user(ID:1367) can send this url to his friends as an invitation.

```
http://example.com/users/sign_up?invitation=1367
```

Then Users table has hidden column called `invitation`.

and This is procedure how it works that I want.

1. His friend input information to sign up.
2. He hits submit button then hidden field 'invitation' will be also sent to form.
3. `1367` will be set in the column called 'invitation' of the record.
4. He will receive confirmation mail, and when he clicks on the link, I'd like to add this transaction, and execute only once for his account.
   Of course, this shouldn't be executed when the existing user tried to re-activate.
   Only for the first confirmation for the new user.

**code**

```
@user = User.find_by_invitation(current_user.invitation)
@user.friends = @user.friends + 1
@user.save
```

I already have registration controller that helps adding extra transaction to Devise.
Now I want to know how I can implement this procedure to my app.

Should it be something like this?

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
def after_????????
    if @user = User.find_by_invitation(current_user.invitation)
        @user.friends = @user.friends + 1
        @user.save
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on the user model.  Use a callback called `after_create` which is triggered after a user is created.

```
# user.rb
after_create :handle_invitation_code

private

def handle_invitation_code
  # do something with invitation here
  # i'm assuming that you want to credit
  # whoever it is that invited this user
  # assuming that invitation contains the
  # id of the referrer
  if referrer = User.find_by_id(invitation)
    # do something with referrer
  end
end
```

Be warned that if you return false on a callback, it will cause a rollback and the record won't be saved.

UPDATE: callback for after confirmation

instead of using `after_create`, use `before_save` with an `if` option

```
before_save :handle_invitation_code, if: :just_confirmed?

def just_confirmed?
  confirmed_at_changed? && confirmed_at_was.nil?
end

def handle_invitation_code
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But the point is inerting transaction when after confirmation is completed. Devise creates an user record as soon as sign up is done even if confirmation is not done yet.  I don't want to give a credit for that. I'd give only after email confirmation is completed.

Comment: sorry, i usually get lost with the description of the question that i forget to read the title. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update! Doesn't it work even when the user saves from edit page?

Comment: it wont. it will only work when the confirmed_at attribute was changed from nil to a non-nil value.

Comment: Thanks. and Last question. I did put it into user.rb  However it seems it's going to check and execute just_confirmed method everytime when all the users access to users_controller. Doesn't make my app slower?

Comment: I get this name error:( why? undefined local variable or method `just_confirmed' for UsersController:Class

Comment: that should be `just_confirmed?` and it will only access that method when you are saving a record. the check will only last for a few microsecond so no need for concern about performance

Comment: Thanks I tried that but still the same error. What version of Rails do you use? Did it work on your environment?

Comment: it is weird if you're getting the same error.  make sure that you change the method. it should be `before_save :handle_invitation_code, if: :just_confirmed?`

Comment: I think I understood the situation. You were saying that I have to add it to model, right? I was doing that in controller. But I cannot access to current_user in model. Then How can I archive?

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean.  why do you need the current_user in the model?